# How to add target to UIButton in Swift

Tags: iphone, swift, uibutton, target

I want to add target to multiple buttons with sender parameter in Swift but I'm facing a problem

Here's my code

```
var index = 10
var btn = [UIButton]()

for var i = 0; i<=index; i++
{
btn.append(UIButton(frame : ... ))
btn[i].addTarget(self, action: "event_clicked", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
}

func event_clicked(sender : UIButton!)
{
sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```

it runs well but when I press one of the buttons, the error "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" shows. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself. Must write the selecter name "event_name:". Has to put the colon at the end of the selecter name.